# Why doesn't "g controller" also create view file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

I've seen some **Rails** examples where generating a controller also creates the view file (not just the view folder).

In section *6.4* of [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#generating-a-controller), it shows an empty view folder and no view file.  This is what my local installation is doing.  I don't get any view files.

Is there some way to have **Rails** auto generate the view file when running `rails g controller ...`?  Or, is it more likely the person created the view file manually and didn't show that part?

Comment: application.rb has nothing to do with that issue ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [rails generate scaffold](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.8/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running-quickly-with-scaffolding) instead which will generate the model, view and controller files for you in a single operation.

> If you want to create the models, views, and controllers for a new
>   resource in a single operation, scaffolding is the tool for the job.

e.g.:

```
rails g scaffold Post name:string title:string content:text
```

But, if you really want to use `rails g controller` and also create the view files for you, then you have to specify the `action` names for your controller:

```
rails g controller Controllername index show edit update
```

This way, it will create the view files for these four actions: `app/views/.../index.html.erb`, `app/views/.../edit.html.erb` . . . etc.

But, looking at your case, you should use scaffolding as it will do a lot of work for you.

Answer (score 2):

To generate basic view and controller actions you should run e.g.: `rails g controller Controllername index show`

Basic view for index and show action will be created.

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same problem if i create an api-project with RubyMine (New Project > Rails Api Project). The first project was created on cli (rails new), ze second in RM:

```
C:\Projekte\railstest3>ruby bin/rails generate controller Welcome index
      create  app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb
       route  get 'welcome/index'
      invoke  erb
      create    app/views/welcome
      create    app/views/welcome/index.html.erb
      invoke  test_unit
      create    test/controllers/welcome_controller_test.rb
      invoke  helper
      create    app/helpers/welcome_helper.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      invoke  assets
      invoke    coffee
      create      app/assets/javascripts/welcome.coffee
      invoke    scss
      create      app/assets/stylesheets/welcome.scss

C:\Projekte\railstest3>cd..

C:\Projekte>cd railstest

C:\Projekte\railstest>ruby bin/rails generate controller Welcome4 index
      create  app/controllers/welcome4_controller.rb
       route  get 'welcome4/index'
      invoke  test_unit
      create    test/controllers/welcome4_controller_test.rb

C:\Projekte\railstest>rails -v
Rails 5.0.2
```

Solution is to create new "Application Projects" and not new "Api Project" in RM.